# Playa ext.playa.php error

Tags: playa, php-errors

After moving my deployment to a VM for development purposes I now am getting  this error on my pages.

```
Severity: Notice    
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: playa/ext.playa.php
Line Number: 175
```

and

```
Severity: Warning    
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/feeney/webroot/control/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 409
```

I am not clear as to why this is occuring, the pages displays most of the data except those relating to playa.

Comment: What version of Playa are you using?

Comment: We are currently using Playa 4.3

Comment: Can you try updating? Lots of bugs have been fixed since 4.3.